# BASH script to copy files based on date, with a catch

Tags: bash, date, file, copy

Let me explain the tree structure: I have a network directory where several times a day new .txt files are copied by our database. Those files sit on directory based on usernames. On the local disk I have the same structure (directory based on usernames) and need to be updated with the latest .txt files. It's not a sync procedure: I copy the remote file to a local destination and I don't care what happens with it after that, so I don't need to keep it in sync. However I do need to copy ONLY the new files and not those that I already copied. It would look something like:

Remote disk

/mnt/remote/database 
+  user1/
+  user2/
+  user3/
+  user4/

Local disk

/var/database 
+  user1/
+  user2/
+  user3/
+  user4/

I played with

```
find /mnt/remote/database/ -type f -mtime +1
```

and other variants, but it's not working very well.

So, the script i am trying to figure is the following:
1- check /mnt/remote/database recursively for *.txt
2- check the files date to see if they are new (since the last time I checked, maybe maintain a text file with the last time checked on it as a reference?)
3- if the file is new, copy it to the proper destination in /var/database (so /mnt/remote/database/user1/somefile.txt will be copied to /var/database/user1/)

I'll run the script through a cron job.

I'm doing this in C right now, but the IT people are not very good in debugging or writing C and if they need to add or fix something they can handle bash scripts better, which I am not very good at.

Any ideas out there?

thank you!

Comment: i am playing with this: http://www.movingtofreedom.org/2007/04/15/bash-shell-script-copy-only-files-modifed-after-specified-date/

Comment: It sounds like you want the UNIX equivalent of `xcopy /s /m`.

Comment: _I do need to copy ONLY the new files and not those that I already copied._ : This sounds **exactly** like you want to use `rsync`. Unless you explicitly specify the option `--delete` for rsync, it just copies, and does not syncing (i.e. remove extraneios files from the target directory). It also takes care about copying only what has changed. Since your idea of a change is the modification time stamp, you will need the option `-u` for rsync. See your _rsync_ man-page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit*: The original link is long gone.  Redirecting to Wayback machine.

The solution is here:

http://web.archive.org/web/20110206061608/http://www.movingtofreedom.org/2007/04/15/bash-shell-script-copy-only-files-modifed-after-specified-date//

Answer (score 3):

you could consider using local rsync between the input & output directories. it has all the options you want to make its sync policy very flexible.

Comment: rsync -urlc --include="*.txt" /mnt/remote/database/ /var/database/ 

for more information on rsync check:
http://samba.anu.edu.au/ftp/rsync/rsync.html

Comment: hmm, i can't seem to be able to find how to make it copy ONLY the files that are newer that a certain date and those ONLY

Comment: in fact, the rsync will only copy files that are newer than the last call.
if you need to have a specific period excluded, you could use a find command like the one in the response below (using -mtime +xx) pipe it to the rsync adding the option --exclude_from=-

Answer (score 1):

```
find /mnt/remote/database/ -type f -newer $TIMESTAMP_FILE | xargs $CP_COMMAND
touch $TIMESTAMP_FILE
```

Comment: I would make `$CP_COMMAND` a script with its first command doing the `touch` in order to reduce race conditions.

Comment: I think this is a little too blunt to be used to avoid race conditions...rsync is the real answer.

Comment: OK, the scripts in http://www.movingtofreedom.org/2007/04/15/bash-shell-script-copy-only-files-modifed-after-specified-date/ are working great, now I need to figure out how to recurse the directories, grab the name of the directory and pass it to the copy script...